# Why this print changing the following result?

Tags: python

Sample code:

```
p = map(some_logic)
print(list(p)) # HERE
p = filter(some_logic, p)
print(list(p))
```

Using the above code, `p` generated by first line is always the same. But by adding the line commented *HERE*, the last print gives `[]` as output. Without the *HERE* line, the last `print` gives correct content of `p`.

What's causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the result of a `map` call it is consumed:

```
>>> p = map(int, ['1', '2'])
>>> p
<map object at 0x02C878B0>
>>> list(p)
[1, 2]
>>> list(p)
[]
```

You should instead store the result of changing the `map` to a `list`:

```
>>> p = list(map(int, ['1', '2']))
>>> p
[1, 2]
>>> p = list(filter(lambda x: x == 1, p))
>>> p
[1]
```

<sub>Note the same thing happens with `filter` hence I've assigned that changed to a `list` too.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Was not aware those side effects of Python.

Comment: @Magicloud It's not so much a side effect, `map` and `filter` return iterators rather than lists as it allows the result to be used in a `for .. in` loop for example, which uses less memory than storing the result all at once.

Comment: I can see why Python3 has those Map/Filter objects. One thing weird is that after list (which went through the object), I can again list the object without getting errors but unexpected result.